# Google Data Studio - Color picker is cut off (a bug or is it just me?)

Tags: looker-studio, color-picker

When trying to edit colors in Google Data Studio, the color picker dialog box is always cut off. As if it's running off the edges of the screen.

Scrolling up/down doesn't make the picker move. Refreshing the page doesn't do anything. And you can't just click and drag it to move it.

[This shows what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do8Yi.png)

I've reported it on Google's Issue Tracker, but I can't seem to post anything on the Data Studio community forums. Which is why I'm here. I'll also post about it on Reddit to see if anyone else is running into this glitch.

Comment: **Needs Details**: Share a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report [TO-DO] that reproduces a specific issue, using sample data, showing 1) Input values [TO-DO], 2) Expected output [TO-DO] 3) An issue / attempt at solving the issue [TO-DO]). Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case and it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion & the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart Configuration, Temporary Issue, etc

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the problem, so it is not "just you".

However, to reproduce I had to reduce the size of the browser window (with the window maximized it does not happen).  This is clearly a [responsive web design problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) and I guess you're using a small screen.

Although it is indeed a bug, it may not be a priority for Google to solve.  You're probably one of the few users that designs dashboards with small screens.  So you may want to find a bigger screen.

Comment: The bizarre part is it doesn't happen all the time. Just some of the graphs/charts. Since I don't know how to make my window bigger (it's already taking up my whole screen), I messed with zooming in/out. At 80% (or just anything lower than 100%), more of the color picker box was showing up. So that's interesting.

Comment: @404_devNotFound to make your window bigger you must change the screen resolution, but you can only do this if your screen supports bigger resolutions. If you are using a notebook with is small screen, you are probably out of luck and you may need to buy a new screen.